# how can i install intel HAXM in windows 32 bit Computer?

Tags: android, intel, haxm

I have Installed `Android Studio 2.1.2` and when i create emulator with Marshmallow SD it shows intel `HAXM` is not installed.I download intel `HAXM` from sdk manager and then try to install it from folder named "Extras" it shows "**invalid 32 bit application**".so i download intel `HAXM` for windows and successfully installed and also enable virtual technology from BIOS.but still when i run `emulator` it shows intel `HAXM` is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Open a CMD from your installation folder (extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager probably).

In CMD try this command: **intelhaxm-android.exe -f newFolder**. That will extract the information from **intelhaxm-android.exe** and place it on your newFolder. After that, open your newFolder and run **hax.msi** (which I think is the 32bit version). You're all set!

Hope it works.